# Loading gif while form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this JS on a button `class="submit"`:

```
$( ".submit" ).click(function( event ) {
                    
        if(some checks){
            ...
        }else{
            $("#importForm").submit(function(event){
                alert("Submitted");
            });
        }
    });
```

But the form is never submitted, and the alert never pop.
If I drop the:

```
function(event){
  alert("Submitted");
}
```

It's working well. Any idea?

Edit :

Actually what I want to do is display a loading gif while the form is submitted, like I do with `load()` in another view:

```
$("body").load(url, function(){ 
  $('#LoadingGif').empty();
});      
$('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="/assets/image/loader.gif" width=31 height=31 alt="Loading image" />');
```

Comment: Looks like `some checks` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: try put: else { alert('I'm here'); .... } just for know if pass on to  this block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
$("#importForm").submit(function(event){
    alert("Submitted");
});
```

adds an event listener to the element (presumably a `<form>`), but doesn't call it. So if `.submit` is not a button within the form you should change it to:

```
$( ".submit" ).click(function( event ) {

    if(some checks){
        ...
    }else{
        $("#importForm").submit(function(event){ // add event listener
            alert("Submitted");
        }).submit(); // actually submit the form
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2yz6a9L5/1/

Answer to Edit :
You'd have to send the form data using AJAX, because submitting a form the standard way makes a new request, so the current page unloads and the browser waits for the response from your server, which means there's no place to display the gif.

Comment: You'd have to send the form data using AJAX, because submitting a form the standard way makes a new request, so the current page unloads and the browser waits for the response from your server, which means there's no place to display the gif.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form#you_form_id').submit(function(){
     $('div#wait_overlay').show();
});
});
```

and the overley div code will be:

```
<div id="wait_overlay"  style="opacity: 0.5; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1001;">
<img src="/assets/image/loader.gif" width=31 height=31 alt="Loading image" />
</div>
```

Place div#wait_overlay just after the opening body tag.